# Выпадающее меню!

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать, чтобы когда выбираешь цифру, она заменяла ноль!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

```js
p.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let s = document.querySelector('.s');
  s.classList.toggle('db');
  for( let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.btn-standard').length; i++ ){
    document.querySelectorAll('.btn-standard')[i].onclick = function(e){
      p.innerHTML =  document.querySelectorAll('.btn-standard')[i].innerHTML;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#p{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.s{
  display: none;
}
.db{
  display: block;
}

.btn-standard{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">
  0
</div>
<div class="s">
  <div class="btn-standard">1</div>
  <div class="btn-standard">2</div>
  <div class="btn-standard">3</div>
  <div class="btn-standard">4</div>
  <div class="btn-standard">5</div>  
</div>
```

1. Вот так ?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [select](http://htmlbook.ru/html/select) в Вашем `HTML` коде для создания выпадающего списка.

```css
#selection{
  height:30px;
  width:50px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius:5px;
  
}
```

```html
<select id='selection'>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ну или так :)) (какой-то текст )